# how to reflect a vector across a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

So now I have an equation for a plane, i.e. $2x+y-z=0$. I can easily find its normal vector i.e. $(2,1,-1)$ and two basis vectors (by substituting $z$ in terms of $x$ and $y$), which are $(1,0,2)$ and $(0,1,1)$. By using  these three vectors I can form a basis for the whole $\Bbb R^3$ vector space.

Now I'm trying to define a linear transformation $T$ that reflects vectors across the plane, and want to find a formula for $T(x,y,z)$. The question arises when I transform each basis vector and express the result as a combinations the basis vectors. How do the normal vectors and other two basis vectors change after the linear transformation?
I know that the sign of the basis vectors will change but I just don't know how their magnitude will change and why.

Answer (score 1):

As the name suggests, the plane acts as the reflecting mirror. Laws of optics says for an object in front of the mirror the image is formed on the other side of the mirror at the same distance as the object.

So drop a perpendicular from the object (assumed a point) to the mirror (the plane)  after it hits the mirror  extend it beyond by the same distance, that is where the image is formed.

Your question says "how and why the basis vectors change". What is meant by  such statement is given a basis one can associate another basis obtained by reflected image of the given  basis. SO "why" part of the question is settled.

What is tacitly assumed is the reflected images  remain linearly independent hence a basis: that is true because reflection is a 1-1 transformation. Two different points will have different images under reflection.

So nothing is changing. It is a way of saying.

Answer (score 0):

Call the reflection $T$. Then $T$ fixes vectors in the plane and maps vectors orthogonal to the plane to their negatives. (This corresponds to the fact that vectors in front of the mirror reflect to appear behind the mirror.)